# Как получить 15 последовательных цифр?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть строка, которая содержит символы. И в этой строке есть 15 цифр, которые идут последовательно. Мне нужно в получить эти 15 цифр в переменную.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/\d{15}/', $text, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Не, ну элементарно же =/